# I want to link as WINDOWS instead of CONSOLE : LNK 2019 and LNK 1120

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm learning DirectX11 with '3D Game Programming with Direct3D 11.0', and I got trouble. At Chapter 4, example source doesn't run. I don't know why this is happening, and how to fix it.

- I'm using UNICODE.
- At Linker -> System, WINDOWS. At C/C++ -> PreProcessor, WINDOWS.
- At Linker -> Advanced, Entry Point is blank.

This is Source code.

```
#include "d3dApp.h"
#include <Windows.h>

class InitDirect3DApp : public D3DApp
{
public:
    InitDirect3DApp(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    ~InitDirect3DApp();

    bool Init();
    void OnResize();
    void UpdateScene(float dt);
    void DrawScene(); 
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
                   PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    // Enable run-time memory check for debug builds.
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
#endif

    InitDirect3DApp theApp(hInstance);

    if( !theApp.Init() )
        return 0;

    return theApp.Run();
}

InitDirect3DApp::InitDirect3DApp(HINSTANCE hInstance)
: D3DApp(hInstance) 
{
}

InitDirect3DApp::~InitDirect3DApp()
{
}

bool InitDirect3DApp::Init()
{
    if(!D3DApp::Init())
        return false;

    return true;
}

void InitDirect3DApp::OnResize()
{
    D3DApp::OnResize();
}

void InitDirect3DApp::UpdateScene(float dt)
{

}

void InitDirect3DApp::DrawScene()
{
    assert(md3dImmediateContext);
    assert(mSwapChain);

    md3dImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(mRenderTargetView, reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&Colors::Blue));
    md3dImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH|D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    HR(mSwapChain->Present(0, 0));
}
```

This is error message.

```
error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
fatal error LNK1120 : 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried `int main () {}` at the bottom of the code, and it run. But there's no window.

My setting's are WINDOWS, but it run as CONSOLE. I don't know why.

I'm waiting for your answer. Have a good day :)

Comment: which IDE are you using ?

Comment: Did you compile with _WINDOWS defined or _CONSOLE defined? And what do you mean it starts as CONSOLE, not as WINDOWS?

Comment: Why do you add "LNK 2019 and LNK 1120" to your question title but don't mention it in the question itself?

Comment: @Abhineet Window 8.1, Visual studio 2010. And at 2013, same problem is occured.

Comment: @WernerHenze I didn't compile it with _WINDOWS or _CONSOLE.
I mean as I write. My setting is WINDOWS setting. But it run as CONSOLE. It have to need WinMain() , but it require main ().
I add it under the source code.

Comment: When creating a new Project then Visual Studio adds _CONSOLE or _WINDOWS to the preprocessor definitions, depending on the type of project. You should also have the right value set.